# Grid Data is not loading from xml

Tags: xml, extjs

I created a grid and now I am trying to load grid data and column from xml.
My Column is coming from header tag and its loading but data which is coming from G tag is not loading.
Code :

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.fields = [];
    this.columns = [];
    this.data = [];
    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'XML/hart.xml',
                        scope: this,
                        timeout: global_constants.TIMEOUT,
                        method: "GET", 
                        disableCaching: true,
                        failure: function(response) {
                            utils.showOKErrorMsg(sdisMsg.ajaxRequestFailed);
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            debugger;
                            var datas = response.responseXML;
                            Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("HEADER"), function(header) {
                                this.buildField(header);
                                this.buildColumn(header);
                            }, this);
                            Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("G"), function (columnData) {
                                this.fieldLength = this.fields.length;
                                this.record = [];
                                for (i = 0; i < this.fieldLength; i++) {
                                    this.record.push(columnData);
                                }                   
                                this.data.push(this.record);
                            }, this);
                                this.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                    fields : this.fields
                                });
                                this.store.loadData(this.data);
                        }
                    });
    buildField: function(header) {
    this.fields.push({
        name: header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX")
    });
    buildColumn: function(header) {
    var hiddenflg = !(header.getAttribute("VISIBLE"));
    if (header.getAttribute("VISIBLE") == "false")
        hiddenflg = true;
    var strHeaderName = '';
    if ((Ext.isIE && !PC.common.isIE10()))
        strHeaderName = header.text;
    else
        strHeaderName = header.textContent;
    var strToolTip = "";
    this.columns.push({
        header: Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(strHeaderName),
        tooltip: strToolTip,
        dataIndex: header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX"),
        width: parseInt(header.getAttribute("LENGTH")),
        metaID: header.getAttribute("M"),
        enableHdMenu: false,
        hidden: hiddenflg,
        menuDisabled: true,
        sortable: false,
        scope: this,
        /*renderer : function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
            debugger;

        },*/
        fixed: false,
        expanded: true
    });
},
}
```

Code for grid :
In grid I am giving store and columns.

```
{xtype: 'panel',
                title: "Search Result",
                height:500,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    id: 'COHART_GRID',
                    autoHeight: true,
                    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
                    frame: true,
                    store: this.store,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    stripeRows: true,
                    columns: this.columns,
                    bbar: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Exclude',
                        handler: function() {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Include',
                        handler: function() {
                            //debugger;
                        }
                    }]
                }]

            }
```

I will post my xml if need. Thanks for help.

Comment: my Xml is 
<R>
  <HEADERS GROUPSET="">
    <HEADER VISIBLE="true" LENGTH="60" ISSORTABLE="true" DATATYPE="String" DATAINDEX="T" ISKEY="true" DOMAIN="">Study ID</HEADER>
    <HEADER VISIBLE="true" LENGTH="200" ISSORTABLE="true"  DATATYPE="String" DATAINDEX="TT" ISKEY="true" DOMAIN="">Study Title</HEADER>
    <HEADER VISIBLE="true" LENGTH="100" ISSORTABLE="true"  DATATYPE="String" DATAINDEX="STT" ISKEY="true" DOMAIN="">Study drug</HEADER>    
  </HEADERS>
  <DATA>
    <G T="14387" STT="Regafenib" TT="Phase III "  />
    <G T="15808" STT="REGORAFENIB 160 mg" TT="II"  />
  </DATA>
</R>

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `buildField` function you are correctly using getAttribute to access the attributes, but in `this.record.push(columnData);` you are lacking it.

I think want something along the lines of

```
this.record = [];
for (i = 0; i < this.fieldLength; i++) {
    var fieldName = this.fields[i].name
    this.record[fieldName] = columnData.getAttribute(fieldName);
}
```

Untested and without warranty, but that should be about it.

Comment: after applying this my data in this.store is coming like EXL
:
""
STU
:
""
SUB
:
""

Comment: Your suggested edit seems to indicate that your store is an `arraystore`, while most Ext stores in the wild are `jsonstore`, which is the store type that my code is intended for.

Comment: I am using ArrayStore. I am getting column and row details from xml.